# How can I choose optimal values for block size and blocks number for badblocks?

Tags: hard-disk, badblocks

I'd like to test my hard disks with `badblocks`, but I don't know which values I should use for the block size (`-b` option) and blocks number (`-c` option). I randomly tried a few values and it seems they can significantly change the speed of the process. But how can I choose the optimal values?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [How do I choose the right parameters when using badblocks?](http://askubuntu.com/q/59425) and [Using \`badblocks\` on modern disks.](http://superuser.com/q/528176).

Comment: @doktor5000 the same question on different sites of the SE network is not considered a duplicate and there is no way of marking it as such. If it were from the same poster, that would be considered cross-posting which is something we don't like, but different users with the same issue on different sites is not considered a problem. Oh, and to format links in comments, you need to write: `[link text](http://www.linktarget.com)`.

Comment: @terdon: Thanks for the explanation and editing my comment :)
As my answer has been automatically converted to a comment as a *trivial answer* what would be the preferred way to answer this question, if the provided links already contain this information and more details? Copy & paste the relevant stuff again here, wouldn't that be suboptimal?

Comment: @doktor5000 yes, it is suboptimal. Unfortunately, it is also the only choice available. I had actually posted [a meta question](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/1396/) about this a while back. The best thing to do is to combine the information from the other answers into your own, making sure you give credit to the original authors.

Comment: @terdon: Thanks for the link, did it like it was suggested there, including marking the answer as community wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the relevant excerpts for the same question which have been answered already at [How do I choose the right parameters when using badblocks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59425/how-do-i-choose-the-right-parameters-when-using-badblocks) and [Using `badblocks` on modern disks.](https://superuser.com/questions/528176/using-badblocks-on-modern-disks)

There is a [badblocks benchmark script available](https://askubuntu.com/a/400685) that should suit your purpose.

With regards to the `-b` option: this depends on your disk. Modern, large disks have 4KB blocks, in which case you should set `-b 4096`. You can get the block size [from the operating system](https://superuser.com/questions/121252/how-do-i-find-the-hardware-block-read-size-for-my-hard-drive) (e.g. `lsblk -o NAME,PHY-SeC /dev/sdX`), and it's also usually obtainable by either reading the disk's information off of the label, or by googling the model number of the disk. If `-b` is set to something larger than your block size, the integrity of `badblocks` results can be compromised (i.e. you can get false-negatives: no bad blocks found when they may still exist). If `-b` is set to something smaller than the block size of your drive, the speed of the `badblocks` run can be compromised. I'm not sure, but there may be other problems with setting `-b` to something smaller than your block size, since it isn't verifying the integrity of an entire block, it might still be possible to get false-negatives if it's set too small.

The `-c` option corresponds to how many blocks should be checked at once. Batch reading/writing, basically. This option does not affect the integrity of your results, but it does affect the speed at which `badblocks` runs. `badblocks` will (optionally) write, then read, buffer, check, repeat for every N blocks as specified by `-c`. If `-c` is set too low, this will make your `badblocks` runs take much longer than ordinary, as queueing and processing a separate IO request incurs overhead, and the disk might also impose additional overhead per-request. If `-c` is set too high, `badblocks` might run out of memory. If this happens, `badblocks` will fail fairly quickly after it starts. Additional considerations here include parallel `badblocks` runs: if you're running `badblocks` against multiple partitions on the same disk (bad idea), or against multiple disks over the same IO channel, you'll probably want to tune `-c` to something sensibly high given the memory available to `badblocks` so that the parallel runs don't fight for IO bandwidth and can parallelize in a sane way.

*I have this answer as community wiki for further improvement*

Comment: I hoped for a universal formula to calculate the value of ``-c``. I will try the benchmark script instead.

Comment: Did you read the linked threads? They mention that mostly -c does not make any difference, and in the example benchmark results you can see that the time only increases when you choose nondefault, suboptimal settings.

Comment: I don't think so. In my case using the default ``-c`` value (that is, omitting it) is significantly slower than using higher values (32768 or 65536).

Comment: Can you add some explanation for the "If -b is set to something larger than your block size, the integrity of badblocks results can be compromised" part? Why can that happen?

Comment: @Alexandros: You may want to ask the author of the original answer from [Using badblocks on modern disks](https://superuser.com/questions/528176/using-badblocks-on-modern-disks) as this one is basically only an excerpt, as noted above.