# How do I determine what files are affected by bad blocks on a disk that uses LUKS and XFS?

Tags: luks, xfs, badblocks

Here is my setup: no partition, just LUKS1 and then XFS inside that.

To confirm, the disk was set up like so: disk is installed, luksFormat, luksOpen, mkfs.xfs, mount, start using.

First of all, what block size do I use for badblocks? Seems like:

[How can I choose optimal values for block size and blocks number for badblocks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202541/how-can-i-choose-optimal-values-for-block-size-and-blocks-number-for-badblocks)

```
lsblk -o NAME,PHY-SeC /dev/sdb
```

result: 4096

I ran badblocks on the physical device, ie:

```
badblocks -b 4096 /dev/sdb -sv
```

and it found three bad blocks.

Now I need to try and untangle the combination of LUKS and XFS to determine which files might be corrupted.

What size is the LUKS1 header?

There is conflicting information here.

```
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdb
```

payload offset is shown as 4096, but what blocksize would that be?

Maybe I can get the size of the XFS file system in blocks:

```
xfs_info /dev/mapper/my_data:

blocks=976754134
```

(under the "data" row)

badblocks tells me the total number of blocks:

```
badblocks -b 4096 /dev/sdb -sv 

Checking blocks 0 to 976754645
```

so 976754645 + 1 = 976754646 blocks on the disk total, if that's correct.

976754646 (badblocks) - 976754134 (xfs_info) = 512 blocks at the beginning of the disk used for the LUKS1 header it seems like.

However from here:

https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/BadBlockHowto

It says the LUKS header is 16 MB? (Also wouldn't it be MiB?) I know the LUKS2 header is 16 MiB, but unsure about the LUKS1 header. From my test above it seems like 2 MiB, but then how could something like `cryptsetup convert` work if there isn't 16 MiB free space at the beginning of the disk? The existence of `cryptsetup convert` taken along with the smartmontools article seems to imply the block size for the payload offset is 4096.

But I can't figure out how that would fit on the disk, so proceeding assuming 4096 count (payload offset) * 512 byte block size = 2 MiB LUKS1 header offset.

2 MiB offset / 4096 block size = the first 512 blocks on the disk are for the LUKS1 header. Thus, it seems to be like I need to subtract 512 from the output of badblocks, to translate **disk** blocks into **filesystem** blocks.

For example, badblocks tells me block #512 is bad, that would be block #0 in the XFS filesystem, etc.

I now have the XFS block numbers for each bad block.

Now for each  bad block, I do the following:

```
xfs_db -c 'blockget -b <xfs block number>' /dev/mapper/my_data
```

And it will tell me the inode number. But one odd thing here: I noticed the output looks like this:

```
xfs_db -c 'blockget -b 21512351' /dev/mapper/my_data
setting block 3/3847384 to data
setting inode to 7589729572 for block 3/3847384
inode 7589729572 block 21512351 at offset 34534
```

What exactly does that `block 3/3847384` mean?

I log these inode numbers and remount the filesystem.

Next, on the filesystem I do the following:

```
find /mnt/my_data -inum <inode>
```

and it gives me the files affected by these bad blocks.

Next, to test I do the following:

```
dd if=/path/to/file of=/dev/null iflag=direct status=progress
```

However, this doesn't give me any errors for the files I found, and the last rsync I did off the bad drive showed an entirely different file having io errors, which I *can* repro with dd as shown above.

So...where are my errors? Is the LUKS header the wrong size? Is there some sort of additional offset I need to subtract?

Comment: badblocks on a device that you encrypt? That sounds like a problem. A bad block at position 512? You stand elevated chance of losing your LUKS header. I'd probably throw away that storage device, sorry. Very very serious question: are you really forced to use that device? finding multiple bad blocks means, in 2022, that all the built-in error correction facilites of your storage device failed, and that is *rare*, unless the device is really in a state of progressing decay. Don't assume it will remain these three blocks forever! You **will** lose data that you store on this.

Comment: The resulting bad blocks weren't at 512, that was just an example to try and explain the math I was using. I've been backing up this drive via rsync the entire time it's been in use, and yes it is going in the trash. Before I trash it though, I want to try and determine what files might be corrupt (and possibly corrupt on the backup as well).